# What libraries do I need to link my mixed-mode application to?

Tags: linker, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I'm integrating .NET support into our C++ application.
It's an old-school MFC application, with 1 extra file compiled with the "/clr" option that references a CWinFormsControl.

I'm not allowed to remove the linker flag "/NODEFAULTLIB".
(We have our own build management system, not Visual Studio's.)
This means I have to specify all necessary libraries: VC runtime and MFC.

Other compiler options include "/MD"

Next to that: I can't use the linker flag "/FORCE:MULTIPLE" and just add *everything*:
I'm looking for a non-overlapping set of libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved it:

1. link with "/FORCE:MULTIPLE /verbose" (that links ok) and set the output aside.
2. link with "/NODEFAULTIB /verbose" and trace all unresolveds in the output of the previous step and add the libraries 1 by 1.
3. This resulted in doubles: "AAA.lib: XXX already defined in BBB.lib"
4. Then I finally got it:
   Recompiled managed AND unmanaged units with /MD
   and link to (among others):
   mscoree.lib
   msvcmrt.lib
   mfcm80d.lib

Mixing /MT (unmanaged) and /MD (managed) turned out to be the bad idea: 
different(overlapping) libraries are needed.

@ajryan: Dependcy Walker only tells me what dll's are used, not what libraries are linked to when linking.
(e.g. msvcmrt.lib ?)
I think.

Thanks for the answers!

Jan

Answer (score 1):

As a bare minimum:

mscoree.lib
MSVCRT.lib
mfc90.lib (adjust version appropriately)

And iterate from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AppWizard to create a bare-bones MFC app in your style (SDI / MDI / dialog ) and then [put on your depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).